# All Null, Any Null is possible guava Predicate

Tags: java, null, guava, predicate, notnull

I'm currently facing a code readability issue. The problem is the following:

Have three objects

```
// initialization skipped, all of three could be null as result of their initalization
Object obj1;
Object obj2;
Object obj3;
```

I want to create two booleans from them as follows:

```
// all are null
boolean bool1 = (obj1 == null && obj2 == null && obj3 == null); 

// any of them is null

boolean bool2 = (obj1 == null || obj2 == null || obj3 == null);
```

I know guava provides built-in predicates like `isNull` and `notNull`.

Is there a way to implement a custom predicate that fulfills those two booleans? (assuming that `.apply(..)` function would take 3 parameters then)

Comment: Do you need a [precondition](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) or [predicate](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained#Predicates)? Both are different.

Comment: I need predicate implementation with two methods which will cover those two booleans.

Comment: This question is plain wrong: you want a 3-parameters `Predicate`, where only one exists (you can use lists to match that). You want to kill a fly with a bazooka as your code is perfectly readable and makes complete sense; no need to use Guava. Finally, you want to use `Predicate`s for no reason. I'll provide an answer that answer strictly to your question, but it still makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, but the answer is most probably: **Yes, but it makes little sense.**

You can use

```
FluentIterable<Object> it =
    FluentIterable.from(Lists.newArrayList(obj1, obj2, obj3));

boolean allNull = it.allMatch(Predicates.isNull());
boolean anyNull = it.anyMatch(Predicates.isNull());
```

but be assured that it's both much less readable and much slower than doing it the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you insist on having `Predicate`s, which makes absolutely no sense in your use case. So maaartinus' answer is correct, but doesn't provide the answer with predicates. Here is a solution with predicates.

```
Predicate<Iterable<?>> anyIsNull = new Predicate<Iterable<?>>() {
    @Override public boolean apply(Iterable<?> it) {
        return Iterables.any(it, Predicates.isNull());
    }
};

Predicate<Iterable<?>> allAreNull = new Predicate<Iterable<?>>() {
    @Override public boolean apply(Iterable<?> it) {
        return Iterables.all(it, Predicates.isNull());
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
bool1 = anyIsNull.apply(Arrays.asList(obj1, obj2, obj3));
bool2 = allAreNull.apply(Arrays.asList(obj1, obj2, obj3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to implement in vanilla Java 8:

```
/**
 * Check that <b>at least one</b> of the provided objects is not null
 */
@SafeVarargs
public static <T>
boolean anyNotNull(T... objs)
{
    return anySatisfy(Objects::nonNull, objs);
}

/**
 * Check that <b>at least one</b> of the provided objects satisfies predicate
 */
@SafeVarargs
public static <T>
boolean anySatisfy(Predicate<T> predicate, T... objs)
{
    return Arrays.stream(objs).anyMatch(predicate);
}

/**
 * Check that <b>all</b> of the provided objects satisfies predicate
 */
@SafeVarargs
public static <T>
boolean allSatisfy(Predicate<T> predicate, T... objs)
{
    return Arrays.stream(objs).allMatch(predicate);
}

//... other methods are left as an exercise for the reader
```

(See [what and why @SaveVarargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html#heap_pollution))

Usage:

```
    // all are null
    final boolean allNulls1 = !anyNotNull(obj1, obj2, obj3);
    final boolean allNulls2 = allSatisfy(Objects::isNull, obj1, obj2, obj3);

    // any of them is null
    final boolean hasNull = anySatisfy(Objects::isNull, obj1, obj2, obj3);
```

P.S. General note for novice programmers. Guava is great library, but if you want it **only** because of some small and easy bit (like this one, or `Strings.isNullOrEmpty` etc), IMO it's much better for your project to just implement the thing yourself and avoid extra dependency.